# PySpark replace null in column with value in other column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to replace null values in one column with the values in an adjacent column ,for example if i have

```
A|B
0,1
2,null
3,null
4,2
```

I want it to be:

```
A|B
0,1
2,2
3,3
4,2
```

Tried with

```
df.na.fill(df.A,"B")
```

But didnt work, it says  value should be a float, int, long, string, or dict

Any ideas?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

We can use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
    
df.withColumn("B",coalesce(df.B,df.A))
```

Comment: This solution is missing a **from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce**

Answer (score 17):

Another Answer.

If the below `df1` your dataframe

```
rd1 = sc.parallelize([(0,1), (2,None), (3,None), (4,2)])
df1 = rd1.toDF(['A', 'B'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df1.select('A',
           when( df1.B.isNull(), df1.A).otherwise(df1.B).alias('B')
          )\
   .show()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df.rdd.map(lambda row: row if row[1] else Row(a=row[0],b=row[0])).toDF().show()
```

Comment: Thank you, at the end ,  i used coallesce :
df.withColumn("B",coalesce(df.B,df.A))
But your answer is helpful in case anybody else tries this.

Answer (score 0):

Note: [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html#pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce) **will not** replace `NaN` values, only `null`s:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> cDf = spark.createDataFrame([(None, None), (1, None), (None, 2)], ("a", "b"))
>>> cDf.show()
+----+----+
|   a|   b|
+----+----+
|null|null|
|   1|null|
|null|   2|
+----+----+

>>> cDf.select(F.coalesce(cDf["a"], cDf["b"])).show()
+--------------+
|coalesce(a, b)|
+--------------+
|          null|
|             1|
|             2|
+--------------+
```

Let's now create a `pandas.DataFrame` with `None` entries, convert it into `spark.DataFrame` and use `coalesce` again:

```
>>> cDf_from_pd = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({'a': [None, 1, None], 'b': [None, None, 2]}))
>>> cDf_from_pd.show()
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|NaN|NaN|
|1.0|NaN|
|NaN|2.0|
+---+---+

>>> cDf_from_pd.select(F.coalesce(cDf_from_pd["a"], cDf_from_pd["b"])).show()
+--------------+
|coalesce(a, b)|
+--------------+
|           NaN|
|           1.0|
|           NaN|
+--------------+
```

In which case you'll need to first call [replace](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace) on your `DataFrame` to convert `NaN`s to `null`s.