# Pyspark dataframe left join with default values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes  df1 and df2. I am trying to join (left join)

df1:

```
Name     ID       Age
AA       1        23
BB       2        49
CC       3        76
DD       4        27
EE       5        43
FF       6        34
GG       7        65
```

df2:

```
ID      Place
1       Germany
3       Holland
7       India
```

> Final = df1.join(df2, on=['ID'], how='left')

```
    Name     ID       Age    Place
    AA       1        23     Germany
    BB       2        49     null
    CC       3        76     Holland
    DD       4        27     null
    EE       5        43     null
    FF       6        34     null
    GG       7        65     India
```

But I would like to fill the `Place` column with `Name` column value if `place` value is null

Expected output:

```
    Name     ID       Age    Place
    AA       1        23     Germany
    BB       2        49     BB
    CC       3        76     Holland
    DD       4        27     DD
    EE       5        43     EE
    FF       6        34     FF
    GG       7        65     India
```

Solution, I can think of is, once the join is completed, I can check the value of `Place` and replace with `Name` if it's null. Please let me know if there are any other elegant way of solution. Thanks.

Comment: try this: `final = df1.merge(df2,on='ID',how='left').assign(Place=lambda x: x['Place'].fillna(x['Name']))`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am trying to do this in pyspark dataframe. `merge` and `assign` does not work with pyspark dataframe. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Thanks. After some search managed to use as shown in the link below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import coalesce
df1.withColumn("Place",coalesce(df1.Place,df.Name))
```

[Another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42990533/pyspark-replace-null-in-column-with-value-in-other-column)